# AppWidget AdapterViewFlipper not working on item click

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created simple appwidget with AdapterViewFlipper. Displaying data, and flip action working properly, but if I want handle on item click action, this doesn't working. But if I change AdapterViewFlipper on ListView in xml layout, action click item works properly.

class with widget Provider

```
public class KidChildrenAdaperViewFlipperWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static final String WIDGET_ACTION = "WIDGET_ACTION";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT = ".ACTION_NEXT";
public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "ACTION_PREVIOUS";
private static final String ACTION = "ACTION";

public static final String TAG = "KidChildrenListWidget";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String actionButton = (String) (extras == null ? null : extras.get(ACTION));

    if (action.equals(KidChildrenAdaperViewFlipperWidget.WIDGET_ACTION)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Kliknięto: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action) && actionButton != null) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_view_flipper_children);
        switch (actionButton) {
            case ACTION_NEXT: {
                remoteViews.showNext(R.id.advKidWidgetChildren);
            }
            break;

            case ACTION_PREVIOUS: {
                remoteViews.showPrevious(R.id.advKidWidgetChildren);
            }
            break;
        }

        int widgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

        Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetChildAdapterViewFlipperService.class);
        widgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        widgetIntent.setData(Uri.parse(widgetIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_view_flipper_children);

        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.advKidWidgetChildren, widgetIntent);

        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.advKidWidgetChildren, R.id.tvKidWidgetEmptyView);


        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, KidChildrenAdaperViewFlipperWidget.class);
        // Set the action for the intent.
        // When the user touches a particular view, it will have the effect of
        // broadcasting WIDGET_ACTION.
        activityIntent.setAction(WIDGET_ACTION);
        activityIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        widgetIntent.setData(Uri.parse(widgetIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activityIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.advKidWidgetChildren, toastPendingIntent);



        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(context, KidChildrenAdaperViewFlipperWidget.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        previousIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        previousIntent.putExtra(ACTION, ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        PendingIntent previousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, previousIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWVFCPrevious, previousPendingIntent);


        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context, KidChildrenAdaperViewFlipperWidget.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        nextIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        nextIntent.putExtra(ACTION, ACTION_NEXT);
        PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivWVFCNext, nextPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);

    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.d(TAG, "Zakutalizowano widget");
}
```

}

Class with widget service

```
public class WidgetChildAdapterViewFlipperService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new WidgetFactoryADV(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}

public class WidgetFactoryADV implements RemoteViewsFactory {


    private Context context;
    private int appWidgetId;

    private KidDatabaseManager kidDatabaseManager;
    private List<ChildObject> childObjectList;

    public WidgetFactoryADV(Context context, Intent intent ) {
        this.context = context;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        kidDatabaseManager = new KidDatabaseManager(context);
        childObjectList = kidDatabaseManager.getChildren(((ApplicationController) context.getApplicationContext()).getUser(context).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        childObjectList = kidDatabaseManager.getChildren(((ApplicationController) context.getApplicationContext()).getUser(context).getId());

        for (int i=0; i<childObjectList.size(); i++){
            getViewAt(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return childObjectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int i) {

        ChildObject childObject = childObjectList.get(i);

        RemoteViews widgetRow = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_children_adv_item);

        widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetItemChildName, childObject.getName());

        String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(childObject.getPositionCreatedAt() * 1000));
        widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetItemChildPositionTime, Html.fromHtml(String.format(getString(R.string.last_position),
                sdf)));

        Address address = Utils.getAddress(context, childObject.getLatitude(), childObject.getLongitude());
        if (address != null) {
            String thoroughfare = address.getThoroughfare() == null ? "" : address.getThoroughfare();
            String localiyty = address.getLocality() == null ? "" : (", " + address.getLocality());
            String featureName = address.getFeatureName() == null ? "" : (" " + address.getFeatureName());


            widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetItemAddress, thoroughfare + featureName + localiyty);
        }

        widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetItemAccuracy, ChildUtil.getAccuracyIndicator(context, childObject.getAccuracy()));

        ChildUtil.setActivityIconForRemoteView(context, widgetRow, childObject.getActivity());


        widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidgetItemBattery, childObject.getBattery() + " %");

        Intent widgetIntent = new Intent();
        Bundle widgetBundle = new Bundle();

        widgetBundle.putInt("index", i);
        widgetIntent.putExtras(widgetBundle);

        widgetRow.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.rlWidgetADVItem, widgetIntent);


        return widgetRow;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return childObjectList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

I spent a lot of time try solving this problem, but I don't have any idea, why this is not working

Thanks for any suggestion which can help me with this problem

Comment: Hi David, is your problem solved. Please reply?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried solved this issue on many different ways, but without result. In future, I will trying again

Comment: David, I solved the issue by setting fillInClickEvent on child of cell item. If you apply fillInClickIntent on Root view then it will not work but if apply it on child of root view, it works

Comment: I was having this problem too and @SagarTrehan's comment worked. I just made a `FrameLayout` with `match_parent` width and height at the end of my layout inside of the root layout, and set the `fillInIntent` on that view, and it worked...

Comment: I've just checked Sagar's answer, he is right. If you have a child view at the top of the layout - wrap it into RelativeLayout for example, for me it worked. For some reason this issue is related to AdapterViewFlipper, but StackView works fine.